# nginx - How do I serve an index file on a subfolder?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to host a jekyll static site with nginx. I want the site served from a subdirectory in the url, e.g. `https://example.com/jekyll-site/`. The source files are in a git repo, cloned to the `/srv/website/html` folder on the server. When I run `jekyll build`, it creates the site's file in `/srv/website/html/_site`. There is an `index.html` file in `_site` that I want to use for an index directive.

Here's the config I have so far:

```
server {

    # ...

    location / {
        # proxy_pass'es to another process
    }

    location = /jekyll-site {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri/;
    }

    location /jekyll-site/ {
        root        /srv/website/html/_site;
        index       index.html;
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite     /jekyll-site/(.*) /$1 break;
        try_files   $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Now, if I point my browser at `https://example.com/jekyll-site/index.html`, then it serves the index file correctly. If I go to any post in the site, it gets served correctly. All of the internal links from one post to another work correctly. However, if I go to `https://example.com/jekyll-site/`, I get a `404` page, instead of the index page.

What is wrong with my configuration? How do I configure nginx to serve the files from that folder, also with a correct `index` directive?

Comment: Maybe you can remove the `rewrite` and set the try to `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by adding an additional location block with a redirect, like so:

```
server {

    # ...

    location / {
        # proxy_pass'es to another process
    }

    location = /jekyll-site {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri/;
    }

    location = /jekyll-site/ {
        return 302 https://$host${request_uri}index.html;
    }

    location /jekyll-site/ {
        root        /srv/website/html/_site;
        index       index.html;
        rewrite     ^/jekyll-site/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }
}
```

It puts `https://example.com/jekyll-site/index.html` in the address bar of the browser, but at least it works.